# Uncle blocks in Parity PoA blockchain

Tags: blockchain, parity, poa

As I know that there is no competition for mining new blocks in POA blockchain as each node mines new block at its given time slot.
I have a parity PoA blockchain setup with 5 nodes. 
While examining the blockchain, I can see some blocks with Uncle blocks.

Why are there uncle blocks in PoA blockchain?

Answer (score 0):

Clique consensus can actually produce forks and therefore have Uncle blocks as mentioned here: [How does the Clique PoA consensus protocol choose the next block-minting node?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/32722/how-does-the-clique-poa-consensus-protocol-choose-the-next-block-minting-node)

Comment: Although there are forks in clique, uncle blocks are not part of the consensus rules. In the [clique EIP](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/225) the uncle list is explicitely set to an empty list.